# Find the minimum gap (difference) between adjacent elements in a linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

> Write a method called minGap that returns the    minimum gap between
>   adjacent values in a list of integers.  The gap between    two
>   adjacent values in a list is defined as the second value minus the
>   first    value.  For example, suppose a variable called list stores
>   these values:
>
> `[1, 3, 6, 7, 12]`
>
> The first gap is 2 (3 - 1), the second gap is 3 (6 - 3), the third gap is 1
>   (7 - 6), and the fourth gap is 5 (12 - 7).  Thus, the call:
>
> `list.minGap()`
>
> should return 1 because that is the smallest gap.  Notice that the minimum
>   gap could be a negative number.  For example, if list stores the following:
>
> `[3, 5, 11, 4, 8]`
>
> The gaps are 2 (5 - 3), 6 (11 - 5), -7 (4 - 11), and 4 (8 - 4).  Of these
>   values, -7 is the smallest, so it would be returned.
>
> Your method should return 0 if the list has fewer than 2 elements.  You are
>   writing a method for the LinkedIntList class:
>
> ```
>     public class ListNode {
>         public int data;       // data stored in this node
>         public ListNode next;  // link to next node in the list
>
>         <constructors>
>     }
>
>     public class LinkedIntList {
>         private ListNode front;
>
>         <methods>
>     }
> ```
>
> Your method should not modify the list contents and is required to
>   run in    O(n) time where n is the length of the list.  You may not
>   call any other    methods of the LinkedIntList class and you may not
>   construct any structured    objects to solve this problem.

I'm unsure if I'm doing the right thing for checking minimums by setting the `int minGap` to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (let me know if this is bad). I want to get better at these problems, so any tips that can make my code more readable or easier to write would be awesome! I didn't know a lot about using multiple references to linked lists before I solved this problem, so any advice to solving these problems in the future would be much appreciated.

```
public int minGap() {
    if (front == null || front.next == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    int minGap = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    ListNode prev = front;
    ListNode p = front.next;
    while (p != null) {
        int checkGap = p.data - prev.data;
        if (checkGap < minGap) {
            minGap = checkGap;
        }
        prev = p;
        p = p.next;
    }
    return minGap;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to store the whole previous node, just the value. Also, you can replace checking whether the gap is smaller with `min`, although it's mainly a matter of taste. And `p` is a rather opaque variable name

```
public int minGap() {
    if (front == null || front.next == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    int minGap = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int lastValue = front.data;
    ListNode currentNode = front.next;
    while (currentNode != null) {
       minGap = min(minGap, currentNode.data-lastValue);
       lastValue = currentNode.value;
       currentNode = currentNode.next;
    }
    return minGap;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you already checked that `front.next` is non-null, you could rearrange your initializations and initialize `minGap` to:

```
...
ListNode prev = front;
ListNode p = front.next;
int minGap = p.data - prev.data;
...
```

This would make the first iteration of the loop mostly redundant, but ensures `minGap` is always a valid gap value.

Answer (score 2):

You could initialize it to the "error out" value, then use another variable to force it to replace it on the first loop iteration.  Also, since it is initialized to the "error out" value, you can skip one of the error check conditions.

```
public int minGap() {
    int minGap = 0;
    int firstCheck = 1;

    ListNode prev = front;
    if (prev == null) { return minGap; }

    ListNode p = front.next;
    while (p != null) {
        int checkGap = p.data - prev.data;
        if (checkGap < minGap || firstCheck == 1) {
            minGap = checkGap;
            firstCheck = 0;
        }
        prev = p;
        p = p.next;
    }

    return minGap;
}
```

In this arrangement, we are checking both `prev` and `p` for `null` immediately after assigning to them, so it is a little easier to keep the `null` check consistent (for instance if `front.next` gets refactored to some other name, you have two places to change it, rather than three).

Comment: you can also use a boolean rather than an int.